# Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection. From com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity

Tags: android, react-native, android-security

I get this this notify from google play when I summit my react native app.

I have tried many ways, but after 10 time submit to store, it still doesn't work

> Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.

> com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity.sendResult

I have try add this line to my manifest file, but it not work

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" tools:replace="android:exported" android:exported="false">
```

this not work too:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" android:exported="false">
```

[image]